# React Native - Moving the item outside the folder view when holding it

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm writing a folder management system in React Native that looks similar to iOS / android home screen with the functionality of sorting the items by dragging and creating folders. Now i would like to add a functionality of moving the item back from the folder to the main grid. By moving the item on the blurred view (Image 1), the folder should dissapear but the item I'm currently moving should remain "under the finger" to be able to place it somewhere on the main grid (Image 2). The problem is I don't have any idead how to achievie that.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTXwu.png) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSrNZ.png)

Folder Grid code:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 9;
  //calculate how many pages we have

  const [HEIGHT, setHEIGHT] = useState(Dimensions.get('window').height);
  const scrollRef = useRef<Animated.ScrollView | null>(null);
  const sharedOrder = useSharedValue(initialOrder);
  const activeItemIndex = useSharedValue<number>(-1);
  const sharedData = useSharedValue(data);
  const [prevOrder, setPrevOrder] = useState(sharedOrder.value);
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [scrollEnabled, setScrollEnabled] = useState(true);

  const displayedData = useMemo(() => {
    const start = (page - 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
    const end = start + ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
    return sharedData.value.slice(start, end);
  }, [sharedData.value, page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    sharedOrder.value = displayedData.map(item => item.index);
  }, [sharedOrder.value, displayedData]);

  console.log('displayedData: ', displayedData);

  const numPages = useMemo(
    () => Math.ceil(sharedData.value.length / ITEMS_PER_PAGE),
    [sharedData.value.length],
  );

  const numPerRow = useMemo(
    () => Math.floor(parentWidth / (itemWidth + 2 * itemMargin)),
    [itemWidth],
  );

  const usableWidth = useMemo(
    () => numPerRow * (itemWidth + 2 * itemMargin),
    [itemWidth, numPerRow],
  );

  const offsetX = useMemo(() => (parentWidth - usableWidth) / 2, [usableWidth]);

  const scrollHeight = useMemo(() => {
    const rows = Math.floor((data.length - 1) / numPerRow) + 1;
    const _scrollHeight =
      offsetY + (itemHeight + 2 * itemMargin) * rows + itemMargin;
    return Math.max(HEIGHT, _scrollHeight);
  }, [HEIGHT, data.length, numPerRow]);

  const cancelEditing = useCallback(() => {
    setIsEditing(false);
    setScrollEnabled(true);
  }, []);

  const hasOrderChanged = useMemo(
    () => !compareScalarArrays(sharedOrder.value, prevOrder),
    [prevOrder, sharedOrder.value],
  );

  console.log('hasOrderChanged ', hasOrderChanged);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      onChangeDataFinished(sharedData.value);
    }, []),
  );

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      onOrderingFinished(sharedOrder.value);
    }, []),
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasOrderChanged) {
      setPrevOrder(sharedOrder.value);

      console.log('USTAWIAM DATE: ', sharedData.value);
      onChangeDataFinished(sharedData.value);

      onOrderingFinished(sharedOrder.value);
    }
  }, [
    hasOrderChanged,
    onOrderingFinished,
    onChangeDataFinished,
    sharedOrder.value,
    sharedData.value,
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <View style={s.pageCarousel}>
        <Carousel
          ref={c => {
            this._carousel = c;
          }}
          data={Array.from({length: numPages}, (_, i) => i + 1)}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={s.pageCarouselItem}>
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          sliderWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
          itemWidth={60}
          onSnapToItem={index => setPage(index + 1)}
        />
      </View>
      <Styles.Wrapper
        onLayout={event => setHEIGHT(event.nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
        <Styles.CancelPressable onPress={cancelEditing} />
        {displayedData.map((item, index) => (
          <DraggableItem
            key={item.index}
            index={item.index}
            order={sharedOrder}
            initialOrder={initialOrder}
            data={sharedData}
            itemWidth={itemWidth}
            itemHeight={itemHeight}
            margin={itemMargin}
            numPerRow={numPerRow}
            offsetX={offsetX}
            offsetY={offsetY}
            scrollRef={scrollRef}
            isEditing={isEditing}
            setIsEditing={setIsEditing}
            setScrollEnabled={setScrollEnabled}
            cancelEditing={cancelEditing}
            renderItem={() => renderItem(item, index)}
            deleteRenderItem={() => deleteRenderItem(item, index)}
            deleteStyle={deleteStyle}
            activeItemIndex={activeItemIndex}
            openFolder={openFolder}
            onClose={onClose}
            parentWidth={parentWidth}
            parentHeight={parentHeight}
            display={display}
            folderIndex={folderIndex}
          />
        ))}
      </Styles.Wrapper>
    </>
  );
}
```

Draggable Item code :

```
function getPositionFromOrder() {
    'worklet';

    const orderPosition = order.value.findIndex(item => item === index);

    const col = orderPosition % numPerRow;
    const row = Math.floor(orderPosition / numPerRow);

    const x = offsetX + (itemWidth + 2 * margin) * col + margin;
    const y = offsetY + (itemHeight + 2 * margin) * row + margin;
    return {x, y};
  }

  const activeX = useSharedValue(getPositionFromOrder().x);
  const activeY = useSharedValue(getPositionFromOrder().y);

  function clamp(value: number, min: number, max: number) {
    'worklet';

    return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
  }
  function getOrderFromPosition(
    newX: number,
    newY: number,
    translationX: number,
    translationY: number,
  ) {
    'worklet';

    const rightX = newX + itemWidth;
    const leftX = newX;
    const topY = newY;
    const bottomY = newY + itemHeight;
    const centerX = newX + itemWidth / 2;
    const centerY = newY + itemHeight / 2;

    let col;
    let row;

    const centerCol = Math.floor(
      (centerX - offsetX) / (itemWidth + 2 * margin),
    );
    const centerRow = Math.floor(
      (centerY - offsetY) / (itemHeight + 2 * margin),
    );

    if (translationX < 0) {
      col = Math.floor((rightX + 5 - offsetX) / (itemWidth + 2 * margin));
    } else {
      col = Math.floor((leftX - 5 - offsetX) / (itemWidth + 2 * margin));
    }
    if (translationY < 0) {
      row = Math.floor((bottomY + 5 - offsetY) / (itemHeight + 2 * margin));
    } else {
      row = Math.floor((topY - 5 - offsetY) / (itemHeight + 2 * margin));
    }

    const clampedCol = clamp(col, 0, numPerRow);
    const clampedRow = clamp(
      row,
      0,
      Math.floor((order.value.length - 1) / numPerRow),
    );

    const clampedColCenter = clamp(centerCol, 0, numPerRow);
    const clampedRowCenter = clamp(
      centerRow,
      0,
      Math.floor((order.value.length - 1) / numPerRow),
    );

    return {
      col: clampedCol,
      row: clampedRow,
      colCenter: clampedColCenter,
      rowCenter: clampedRowCenter,
    };
  }

  function getOrderPositionFromRowCol(row: number, col: number) {
    'worklet';

    const newOrderPosition = row * numPerRow + col;
    return clamp(newOrderPosition, 0, order.value.length);
  }

  function rearrangeOrder(newOrderPosition: number) {
    'worklet';

    if (!isOutside.value) {
      const newOrder = order.value.filter(orderIndex => orderIndex !== index);

      newOrder.splice(newOrderPosition, 0, index);

      order.value = newOrder;
    }
  }

  function handleRearrange(
    newX: number,
    newY: number,
    translationX: number,
    translationY: number,
  ) {
    'worklet';

    const {col, row, colCenter, rowCenter} = getOrderFromPosition(
      newX,
      newY,
      translationX,
      translationY,
    );
    const newOrderPosition = getOrderPositionFromRowCol(row, col);

    if (colCenter !== col || rowCenter !== row) {
      const indexToSwap = rowCenter * numPerRow + colCenter;
      const indexToSwapOrder = order.value[indexToSwap];
      activeItemIndex.value = indexToSwapOrder;
    } else {
      activeItemIndex.value = -1;
      rearrangeOrder(newOrderPosition);
    }
  }

  function updateOrderAfterRemoval(removedIndex: number) {
    'worklet';

    const newOrder = order.value.filter(
      orderIndex => orderIndex !== removedIndex,
    );

    order.value = newOrder;
  }

  function moveToFolder() {
    'worklet';

    if (
      index === activeItemIndex.value ||
      activeItemIndex.value === undefined
    ) {
      return;
    }
    const updatedData = data.value.map(item => {
      if (item.index === activeItemIndex.value) {
        return {
          ...item,
          name: item.isFolder ? item.name : 'Nowy folder',
          isFolder: item.isFolder ? item.isFolder : true,
          nestedPlayers: item.nestedPlayers
            ? [
                ...item.nestedPlayers,
                data.value.find(item => item.index === index),
              ]
            : [
                data.value.find(item => item.index === activeItemIndex.value),
                data.value.find(item => item.index === index),
              ],
          folderOrder: item.folderOrder
            ? [...item.folderOrder, index]
            : [index],
        };
      }
      return item;
    });

    const filteredData = updatedData.filter(item => item.index !== index);

    updateOrderAfterRemoval(index);

    data.value = filteredData;
  }

  function justDeleteItem() {
    'worklet';

    console.log('index: ', index);
    console.log('folderIndex: ', folderIndex);

    const newData = data.value.filter(item => item.index !== index);

    console.log('newData: ', newData);

    const newOrder = order.value.filter(orderIndex => orderIndex !== index);

    order.value = newOrder;

    console.log('order.value: ', order.value);
    console.log(initialOrder);

    data.value = newData;
  }

  function holdAnimation(value: number) {
    'worklet';

    return withDelay(
      200,
      withTiming(value, {
        duration: LONG_PRESS_DURATION - 200,
        easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.quad),
      }),
    );
  }

  function releaseAnimation(value: number) {
    'worklet';

    return withTiming(value, {
      duration: LONG_PRESS_DURATION,
      easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.quad),
    });
  }

  const eventHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: (event, ctx) => {
      ctx.startX = activeX.value;
      ctx.startY = activeY.value;
    },
    onActive: (event, ctx) => {
      if (isHeld.value) {
        isMoving.value = true;
        const newX = ctx.startX + event.translationX;
        const newY = ctx.startY + event.translationY;

        const translationX = event.translationX;
        const translationY = event.translationY;

        console.log('newY: ', newY);
        console.log(parentHeight);
        if (newY < 0 - itemHeight || newY > parentHeight - 60) {
          // const filteredData = data.value.filter(item => item.index !== index);

          // updateOrderAfterRemoval(index);

          // data.value = filteredData;
          isOutside.value = true;

          if (isOutside.value) {
            console.log('isOutside: ', isOutside.value);
            // display.value = 'none';
          }
          // runOnJS(onClose)();
        } else {
          isOutside.value = false;
          console.log('isOutside: ', isOutside.value);
          // display.value = 'flex';
        }

        // console.log('index: ', index);
        // console.log('activeItemIndex.value: ', activeItemIndex.value);

        activeX.value = newX;
        activeY.value = newY;

        handleRearrange(newX, newY, translationX, translationY);
      }
    },
    onEnd: (event, ctx) => {
      scale.value = releaseAnimation(1);
      if (isHeld.value) {
        const newX = ctx.startX + event.translationX;
        const newY = ctx.startY + event.translationY;

        const translationX = event.translationX;
        const translationY = event.translationY;

        activeX.value = newX;
        activeY.value = newY;

        if (activeItemIndex.value !== -1 && !isOutside.value) {
          moveToFolder();
        }

        if (isOutside.value) {
          console.log('usuwam: ', index);
          justDeleteItem();
        }

        // display.value = 'flex';

        handleRearrange(newX, newY, translationX, translationY);
      }

      runOnJS(setScrollEnabled)(true);
      isHeld.value = false;
      isMoving.value = false;
    },
  });

  function handleReposition() {
    'worklet';

    const {x, y} = getPositionFromOrder(); // TODO: Might need to pass order as a param
    activeX.value = withSpring(x, springConfig);
    activeY.value = withSpring(y, springConfig);
  }

  useAnimatedReaction(
    () => activeItemIndex.value,
    activeIndex => {
      scaleHovered.value = withTiming(activeIndex === index ? 1.1 : 1, {
        duration: 300,
        easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.quad),
      });
    },
  );

  useAnimatedReaction(
    () => JSON.stringify(order.value),
    (result, previous) => {
      if (result !== previous && !isHeld.value) {
        handleReposition();
      }
    },
  );

  useAnimatedReaction(
    () => isHeld.value,
    (result, previous) => {
      if (result !== previous) {
        handleReposition();
      }
    },
  );

  useAnimatedReaction(
    () => isEditing,
    (result, previous) => {
      const cycleTime = 150;
      const distance = 1.5;
      if (result && !previous) {
        rotation.value = withSequence(
          withTiming(-distance, {duration: cycleTime / 2}),
          withRepeat(withTiming(distance, {duration: cycleTime}), 0, true),
        );
        deleteScale.value = withSpring(1, {damping: 12, mass: 1});
      } else if (!result && previous) {
        rotation.value = withTiming(0, {duration: cycleTime / 2});
        deleteScale.value = withTiming(0, {
          duration: 200,
          easing: Easing.out(Easing.quad),
        });
      }
    },
  );

  const triggerHapticFeedback = useCallback(() => {
    ReactNativeHapticFeedback.trigger('impactMedium');
  }, []);

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const isHovered = activeItemIndex.value === index;
    return {
      transform: [
        {
          translateX: activeX.value,
        },
        {
          translateY: activeY.value,
        },
        {
          scale: isHovered ? scale.value * scaleHovered.value : scale.value,
        },
        {
          rotateZ: `${rotation.value}deg`,
        },
      ],
      zIndex: isHeld.value ? 99 : 0,
    };
  });

  const deleteAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [
      {
        scale: deleteScale.value,
      },
    ],
  }));

  return (
    <PanGestureHandler
      simultaneousHandlers={[scrollRef, longPressRef]}
      ref={panRef}
      onGestureEvent={eventHandler}>
      <Styles.AnimatedView
        style={[{width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight}, animatedStyle]}>
        <LongPressGestureHandler
          maxDist={20}
          minDurationMs={LONG_PRESS_DURATION}
          onBegan={() => {
            scale.value = holdAnimation(1.05);
          }}
          onFailed={() => {
            scale.value = releaseAnimation(1);
          }}
          onActivated={() => {
            triggerHapticFeedback();
            setIsEditing(true);
            setScrollEnabled(false);
            isHeld.value = true;
          }}
          onEnded={() => {
            if (!isMoving.value) {
              isHeld.value = false;
            }
            activeItemIndex.value = -1;
            scale.value = releaseAnimation(1);
          }}
          ref={longPressRef}
          simultaneousHandlers={[scrollRef, panRef]}>
          <TapGestureHandler
            onHandlerStateChange={e => {
              const currentItem = data.value.find(item => item.index === index);
              if (
                e.nativeEvent.state === State.END &&
                currentItem &&
                currentItem.isFolder
              ) {
                openFolder(currentItem);
              }
            }}>
            <Styles.InnerAnimatedView
              style={{
                width: itemWidth,
                height: itemHeight,
              }}>
              <Styles.Content>{renderItem()}</Styles.Content>
              {isEditing ? (
                <Styles.CancelPressable onPress={cancelEditing} />
              ) : null}
            </Styles.InnerAnimatedView>
          </TapGestureHandler>
        </LongPressGestureHandler>
        <Styles.AnimatedDeleteView style={[deleteStyle, deleteAnimatedStyle]}>
          {deleteRenderItem()}
        </Styles.AnimatedDeleteView>
      </Styles.AnimatedView>
    </PanGestureHandler>
  );
}
```

FolderView code:

```
return (
    <View>
      <Portal>
        <Animated.View
          entering={FadeIn}
          exiting={FadeOut}
          style={animatedStyle}>
          <BlurView
            {...(Platform.OS === 'ios' && {blurType: 'light'})}
            style={[s.portalContainer]}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
              }}
              onPress={() => {
                onClose();
              }}
            />
            <View style={s.folderNameContainer}>
              <TextInput style={s.folderName}>{folderData.name}</TextInput>
            </View>
            <Animated.View style={[s.folderViewContainer]}>
              <FolderGrid<TileType>
                isFolderGrid={true}
                display={display}
                data={folderData.nestedPlayers}
                openFolder={openFolder}
                onClose={onClose}
                handleDelete={deleteFromFolder}
                initialOrder={order}
                renderItem={item => (
                  <Tile width={itemWidth} height={itemHeight} item={item} />
                )}
                deleteRenderItem={item => (
                  <DeleteButton
                    size={deleteSize}
                    onPress={() => handleDelete(item.index)}
                  />
                )}
                deleteStyle={{left: -deleteSize / 3, top: -deleteSize / 2}}
                onOrderingFinished={newOrder => onFolderOrderChange(newOrder)}
                onChangeDataFinished={newData => onFolderDataChange(newData)}
                itemWidth={itemWidth}
                parentWidth={folderViewContainerWidth}
                parentHeight={folderViewContainerHeight}
                itemHeight={itemHeight}
                itemMargin={margin}
                offsetY={margin}
                folderIndex={folderData.index}
              />
            </Animated.View>
          </BlurView>
        </Animated.View>
      </Portal>
    </View>
  );
}
```